# The explanation of $|R_{XY}(\tau)| \le \sqrt{R_{XX}(0)R_{YY}(0)}$

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation

If i said the explanation of $|R_{XX}(\tau)| \le R_{XX}(0)$ is that in the time domain,any signal wave are the same as itself when it doesn't shift.Then what is the explanation  of $|R_{XY}(\tau)| \le \sqrt{R_{XX}(0)R_{YY}(0)}$ ?Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a (once deleted but now-undeleted) answer by @StanleyPawlukiewicz whose original posting predates the first version of this answer by about two hours (There! Is that enough acknowledgment of priority for you, Stanley?), this is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality which states in general terms  that for signals or vectors $x$ and $y$,
$$\left|\langle x, y\rangle\right| \leq\Vert x \Vert\cdot \Vert y \Vert = \sqrt{\Vert x \Vert^2\cdot \Vert y \Vert^2}.\tag{1}$$
Here, $\langle x, y\rangle$ denotes *an* inner product and $\Vert x \Vert^2 
= \langle x, x\rangle$ is the corresponding squared norm.

For (complex-valued) continuous-time finite-energy deterministic signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, the inner product and squared norm are usually taken to be
$$\langle x, y\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)[y(t)]^* \,\mathrm dt~~ ~~ \text{and}~~ \Vert x \Vert^2  = \langle x, x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt \tag{2}$$
which gives us for deterministic signals that 
$$|R_{X,Y}(\tau)| \stackrel{\Delta}{=} |\langle x(t), y(t+\tau)\rangle| \leq \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt \int_{-\infty}^\infty |y(t+\tau)|^2 \,\mathrm dt} = \sqrt{R_{X,X}(0)R_{Y,Y}(0)}.$$
A similar result holds for discrete-time signals where sums replace the integrals.
Note that it is also possible to use 
$$\langle x, y\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)[y(t)]^*g(t) \,\mathrm dt~~ ~~ \text{and}~~ \Vert x \Vert^2  = \langle x, x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2g(t) \,\mathrm dt$$
where $g(t)$ is any nonnegative real-valued function.

For (finite-variance real-valued) random variables $X$ and $Y$, one can define an inner product of $X$ and $Y$ as 
$$\langle X, Y\rangle  \stackrel{\Delta}{=} E[XY] = 
\int XY \,d\mathbb P \tag{3}$$ where $\mathbb P$ is the probability *measure*.  I brought in the fancy verbiage to emphasize the similarity of $(3)$ to $(2)$ but note the simpler version for jointly continuous random  variables with joint density $f_{X, Y}(x,y)$ for which $(3)$ can be written as
$$E[XY]  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xy \, f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy$$ with corresponding squared norm function $E[X^2]$ which leads to the stochastic version of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
$$|E[XY]| \leq \sqrt{E[X^2]E[Y^2]}.\tag{4}$$ Note that this result holds for discrete random variables as well.

Finally, since random *processes* 
$\{X(t)\}$ and $\{Y(t)\}$ are just *collections* of random variables with the $t$-th random variables in these sets being denoted by $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ respectively, we have from $(4)$ that

$$|R_{X,Y}(\tau)| \stackrel{\Delta}{=} |E[X(t)Y(t+\tau)]| \leq \sqrt{E[(X(t))^2]\cdot E[(Y(t+\tau)^2]} = \sqrt{R_{X,X}(0)R_{Y,Y}(0)}.\tag{5} $$

Comment: do you usually provide the same answer to a question that has been answered?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz chill, your answer was missing the (imho, quite central) point of how to get from CS ineq to the product of zero-lag autocorr coeffs.

Comment: If I have something to add to an answer. I acknowledge that answer in either comments or my own answer. @Marcus Miller. This isn’t the place for further discussion.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz  Your answer was posted while I was composing mine (I took a break between starting writing it and finishing it) and I didn’t see what you had written until after I had posted my answer. I take great offense at your suggestion that I usually write answers that repeat what other answers have already said without acknowledging their priority.  At this time, I am including a reference to your now-deleted answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Given your explanation, I did over react and do apologize. It would have been better if you had looked at he other answers when you did post. There were now 2 posts that were substantially similar. Don’t you think that someone would would have concluded that one was unnecessary? if not vain.

Answer (score 1):

The highest value $R_{XY}$ is where the maxima of $x$ and $y$ are multiplied with each other. The highest value of an autocorrelation $R_{XX}$ or $R_{YY}$ is at a time shift of $\tau=0$, because you are comparing a signal to itself, which is always fully correlated.

Now when you compare two different signals with each other, the most similar to each other they can be is when they are identical, in which case $|R_{XY}|=\sqrt{R_{XX}(0)R_{YY}(0)}$. In any other case, $|R_{XY}|$ is smaller due to the fact that the signals that were correlated with each other are not perfectly identical.

When you multiply the autocorrelations at $\tau=0$ and take the square root, you get the highest possible absolute value of the cross-correlation $R_{XY}$.

On a side note, another interesting property of autocorrelations is that for gaussian random variables, you can easily get the distribution parameters:

$R_{XX}(0) = \mu^2+\sigma^2$

$\lim\limits_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}R_{XX}(\tau)=\mu^2$

This might help you understanding how correlations work!

Comment: So is it mean that  the most similar (biggest autocorrelation)of two signal is  when they didn't shift ?

Comment: while this is true for autocorrelations (correlating a signal with itself), this does not hold for cross-correlations where you correlate a signal with another, different signal.

Comment: so the cross correlation doesn't have explanation like this?

Comment: Hi: Assuming $R_{xx}(0)$ represents  the variance of  $X$ , then your inequality is just another way of saying that the cross correlation of  $X$ and $Y$ at any lag $\tau$ has to be between -1 and +1. This can be shown using the cauchy-schwartz which Stanley's answer already linked to.

Comment: Hi:  I understand what you're saying  with the shifting argument but I don't think that's  a useful viewpoint because  there really is no relationship between variance and auto-covariance aside from the fact that, normalizing the covariance appropriately (auto or cross ), forces it to be between -1 and + 1 at any lag.  IMHO, it's bestt to think of variance and covariance as two very different animals aside from the normalization which is a consequence of Dilip's beautiful derivation. Dilio showed it for the cross case but it also holds in the auto-case.  ( replace y with x everywhere ).

Comment: To the dspers and the OP: With regard to above,   I am aware that the fourier transform of the autocorr is the power spectrum and, if you evaluate it  at lag zero, you get the variance of the process. IMHO, this makes it seems like there is a tangible relationship between covariance and variance ( or autocorr and corr at lag zero ) when, IMHO, that's misleading. You obtain the variance of the process because, when evaluating the power spectrum at lag zero, you end up summing the VARIANCES ( not the covariances, they go away ) over all of the frequencies which results in the total variance. .

Comment: @Shine Sun: I read back my answer and I'm not sure if it's so clear so I'll just say one more thing.  Basically, what I'm saying is that your shifting viewpoint almost implies that the variance is almost some kind of weighted linear combination of the other autocovariances which is not the case.  You can think of it as a special autocovariance because it's the one calculated with zero lag but it's actual value has nothing to do with shifting or the lack thereof. It's  always bigger than the others only because of the cs inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just the Schwarz inequality

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Which is stated in vector form as

$$
\mid <u,v> \mid^2 \le \;<u,u> <v,v>
$$

$< u, u>$ corresponds to $R_{x,x}(0)$. and the rest should be obvious. Both sides are positive, so you can take the square root of both sides.

Leaving the squares is preferable if you want to take derivatives, which is often done in texts.

Kailath and Sayed in:

> Kailath, Thomas, Ali H. Sayed, and Babak Hassibi. Linear estimation.
>   No. EPFL-BOOK-233814. Prentice Hall, 2000.

Use vector notation to express Probabilistic Expectation  i.e. $E\{ x y \}$ is equivalent to $< x ,y >$, so Cauchy Schwarz holds for deterministic as well as probabilistic expectation. which you didn't specify in your question.